# Insert YouTube Video into a popup

Tags: javascript, html, css, youtube

I have a problem  to put youtube video in a popup.
Problem is to insert that. I can't do it with only `<iframe>`. It isn't showing video :(. I put `<iframe>` into a div and it isn't working. I will show you my scripts, css styles and html.

I want to make something like you click on the popup and in this popup is YouTube video shown.

HTML

```
                        <div id="popupBox_1">
                            <div class="popupBoxWrapper">
                                <div class="popupBoxContent">
                                    <h3>Popup 1</h3>
                                    <embed width="420" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LRblJyq_4Ko">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

I tried also method using  and it isn't also working :(.

JavaScript

```
    function toggle_visibility(id) {
    var e = document.getElementById(id);
        if(e.style.display == 'block')
            e.style.display = 'none';
        else
            e.style.display = 'block';
}

window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == popupBox_1) {
        popupBox_1.style.display = "none";
    }
        if (event.target == popupBox_2) {
     popupBox_2.style.display = "none";
    }
    if (event.target == popupBox_3) {
        popupBox_3.style.display = "none";
    }
    if (event.target == popupBox_4) {
        popupBox_4.style.display = "none";
    }
    if (event.target == popupBox_5) {
        popupBox_5.style.display = "none";
    }
    if (event.target == popupBox_6) {
        popupBox_6.style.display = "none";
    }
    if (event.target == popupBox_7) {
        popupBox_7.style.display = "none";
    }
    if (event.target == popupBox_8) {
        popupBox_8.style.display = "none";
   }
   if (event.target == popupBox_9) {
        popupBox_9.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

CSS

```
#popupBox_1 { 
top: 0; left: 0; position: fixed; width: 100%; height: 120%;
background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.7); display: none; border-radius: 10px !important;}
```

Comment: Where are you calling `toggle_visibility`, and where is `popupBox_*` defined? Are there any console errors? (F12 -> Console)

Comment: That isn't required on this thing, i used this to click on <a href> and when you click on this popup is shown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. check it out :

```js
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

btn.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";
}

span.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
}

window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

```css
.modal {
    display: none; /* Hidden by default */
    position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
    padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%; /* Full width */
    height: 100%; /* Full height */
    overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content */
.modal-content {
    background-color: #fefefe;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #888;
    width: 80%;
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
    color: #aaaaaa;
    float: right;
    font-size: 28px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<button id="myBtn">Open Modal</button>

<div id="myModal" class="modal">

  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/LRblJyq_4Ko" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
  </div>

</div>
```

2. Your algorithm to make a modal was not fine !
3. To include an youtube video to your codes, you should use `<ifream>`

Comment: But I don't want to use modals :(

Comment: Popup is working, but I can't insert a YouTube video, I think that i require additional JS code to my script...

Comment: @OliwierPiasecki ok :( so how you open your popup ... ?

Comment: '<div class="row">
        <div class="4u 12u$(mobile)">
         <article class="item">
          <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="toggle_visibility('popupBox_1');" class="image fit"><img src="images/film/min_1.png" alt="" /></a>
          <header>
           <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="toggle_visibility('popupBox_1');">
           <h3>Salezjańskie Szkoły Muzyczne w Lutomiersku</h3>
           </a>
          </header>
         </article>'

Comment: @OliwierPiasecki you add it to the first post :/

Comment: And it means when you click on the picture the popup opens :)

Comment: Ok I don't want to make an argument, ok? I will change it to modals but can someone told  me to not create button? I mean when i click on picture the modal opens :) Can someone explain me this?

Comment: @OliwierPiasecki you can change this line `<button id="myBtn">Open Modal</button>` to this : `<img id="myBtn" src="pic.jpg">`